# Building Android Webkit Plugins?

Tags: android, plugins, webkit, browser-addons

I have an application I built (based on [OilCan](http://oilcan.jsharkey.org/)) that modifies some popular webpages with basic enhancements.

When I distribute it as a .apk, I can launch my new application called MyApp that emulates the browser, editing the target pages to my liking.

Now I'd like to re-package it as a plugin for the default browser, so that if my app is installed, it runs in the base Android Webkit Browser app, instead of requiring the user to launch MyApp every time.

Is this possible? I assume so because this appears to be how Adobe Flash works -- install the .apk, extend the browsers functionality -- but also, that's a content-based plugin, rather than an add-on. I can find no documentation regarding what I want to do; any direction at all would be super helpful!

Thanks, --L

Answer (score 0):

I think the browser is prepared to use the flash plugin (expected extension).

I also did research before whether I can extend the default browser, but only found posts on google group where the developers say that there is no API included which allows browser extension.

I would love to see an API since this would enhance the app so much, but I also can understand their decision since it's a lot of work and wrong extensions could break the efficiency...

E.g. dolphin browser plugins are also all self written, closed API (right now at least).